# Alice has 2 kids and one of them is a girl. What is the probability that the other child is also a girl? (Apply Bayes' Theorem)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I am aware that The outcomes for two kids can be {BB, BG, GB, GG}, and given that there's one girl, the answer would be 1/3. But, when I put the question into a context of Bayesian Theorem, I seem to struggle.

My equation is as follows:
P(2G|1G)=[P(1G|2G)*P(2G)]/P(1G)

where P(1G|2G) = 1 as given there are two girls, the probability of having 1 girl would be 1, P(2G)=0.5*0.5, P(1G)=0.5 .

Where, in my equation, did I get wrong?

Comment: Your question is ambiguously phrased.  It matters why we know that Alice has a girl child.  Regardless, this question has been discussed ad nauseum on this site already.

Comment: The mistake for the traditional approach and interpretation of the problem that you made was in saying $P(1G)=0.5$.  This should be $0.75$ instead.  $P(1G)$ is not the probability that the "first" child is a girl., rather $P(1G)$ is the probability that at least one of the two kids that we know Alice has is a girl that we assume various things about to make the problem work such as independence of gender, etc...

Comment: Go through the possible cases to see the flaw. There are three possibilities for the two kids leading to at least one girl : girl-girl , boy-girl , girl-boy. One of the three possibilities leads to two girls.

Comment: @JMoravitz Of course, we must assume that each combination is equally like , but in the exercise we can assume this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct but you must remember that your P(1G) is the probability of at least one girl i.e. $3/4$.

Then your answer will be correct as well as your method!

Comment: Clear and concise. Thank you!